# Concatenation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, concatenation

My code is this

```
var call_from='fb_test'
jQuery('.test').html("<img src=\"https://wwww.socialappshq.com/images/socialapps/loading.gif\" height=\"15\" width=\"15\" id=\"loading_image_\" + call_from + \">");
```

but it, not correctly concatenate please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write html using javascript, prefer `'` to enclose the strings and `"` to enclose attribute values

```
var call_from='fb_test'
jQuery('.test').html('<img src="https://wwww.socialappshq.com/images/socialapps/loading.gif" height="15" width="15" id="loading_image_' + call_from + '">');
```

Comment: Double quote is missing please review your answer

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code.

```
var call_from='fb_test';
var yourHtml = '<img src="https://wwww.socialappshq.com/images/socialapps/loading.gif" height="15" width="15" id="loading_image_' + call_from + '"/>';
jQuery('.test').html(yourHtml);
```

Answer (score 1):

For concatenation in `JavaScript` **Try this**

```
  var call_from='fb_test'
  jQuery('.test').html("<img src=\"https://wwww.socialappshq.com/images/socialapps/loading.gif\" height=\"15\" width=\"15\" id=\"loading_image_\"" + call_from + "\">");
```

Comment: You also double quote is missing

Answer (score 0):

```
var yourHtml = '<img src="https://wwww.socialappshq.com/images/socialapps/loading.gif" height="15" width="15" id="loading_image_' + call_from + '"/>';
            jQuery('.'+call_from).html(yourHtml);
```